# How do I keep my pants/trousers from getting caught in the gears?

Tags: mountain-bike, clothing-care, 7-speed

I have the unfortunate habit of always getting my jeans stuck in my gears and end up with a nice rip on the seams.

I've used those velcro braces to keep the bottom of my pants leg close to my body but I guess I pedal too close to the gears as those get caught in the gears too.

Comment: Velcro leg straps should work, if you put them on correctly.  Sometimes you need two, though, one near the very bottom and one up higher, to remove the "blouse" effect.

Comment: As a Brit, this title just makes me giggle :)

Comment: I never need any gear or trick, despite I use bikes naked chain, just wear slim jeans.

Comment: @cjk Is there some euphemism that us Americans aren't getting?

Comment: In the UK, trousers are what you wear on your legs. Pants are your underwear :-)

Comment: How about pantaloons?

Comment: In the UK, the title of this question is more of a euphemism than an earnest question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are basically four solutions that do not involve extensive work on your bike:

1. Roll up the pant-leg on the gear-side high enough to stay away from the gears.
2. Wear tight fitting cycling pants that don't flap.
3. Use braces as you have, or [clips such as these](http://www.fiets-onderdelen-online.nl/Broekklem) to keep your flappy pants close enough to your legs.
4. Stuff the pant-leg on the gear side in your socks.

Since option 3 doesn't work for you that leaves you with options 1, 2 or 4. However, when applying the braces or clips, (or stuffing your pant-leg in your socks) are you taking care to make sure all the excess pant-leg material is collected on the outside of your leg, away from the gears?

On the bicycle side: [Chainring guards](http://www.bikeman.com/Chainring_Guards.html) might help a bit, even better is a full [chainguard](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ch.html) but these may be hard to find for your bike.

Comment: Besides that useful strategies, using a chainring guard can also be useful. Not every crankset allows for them, but might be a necessary measure to completely solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Also, as this answer says, the excess pant material should be always, tightly brought to the outer side, away from the chain, and then strapped/clipped.

Comment: I will see if tucking more neatly will help me. Never had much luck with #1 either, always need to readjust -.- If not I will def look at seeing if I can put a Chain guard on my bike. Thanks :)

Comment: The best choice is definitely number 3. After trying all of them extensively and using rubber bands for the longest time the clips provide the best of both worlds. Unlike rubber bands or bands of any kind you don't need to get them over your feet to take the off. Also unlike rubber bands you are not afraid of them snapping and so you don't have to carry around extra with you. Some of the clips will also come with a reflective strip so you will be more visible at night.

Comment: Elastic bands or hairbands are the best. They hold better than clips, you can leave them under your pants all day, so you can't lose them, and they are cheaper to replace if you do. They also come in various colors ;)

Answer (score 12):

I have found that the top of and old sock over a neatly folded trouser leg works well.Cut the top of the sock long enough to cover your pants with leg fully extended to the top of the sprocket.The plus side is you don't ruin good socks stretching them over your pants.

Answer (score 8):

Simple: Just take two rubber bands and stretch them around the bottom of your pants.

Done! :)

Answer (score 7):

When I was a teenager, the "tight roll" was in style. Nowadays I use it nearly every day to keep my pants out of the chain. It works better than anything else I've ever tried, is totally free, and you don't have to carry anything around with you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_rolled_pants

And here's a video about how to do it:

Comment: Nice no-equipment solution. Fashionable, too!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to velcro and clips, you can use ["slap bracelets."](http://www.aliexpress.com/product-fm/471599199-11-8-x-1-2-reflective-slap-bracelets-wholesalers.html)

Badge holder lanyards from conventions work well, too (but only the ones with alligator clips).  Wrap it once around, put the clip end through the closed end and pull it tight.  The clip will hold it tight.  (pics later)

Answer (score 4):

Get a 8 - 12" piece of velcro, loop side, then adhere a 3" self sticking hook side on the end of the inside. Tuck and wrap. $1.50 cost.

I have had mine for 5 years, using it almost daily with no issues.

Comment: You're essentially describing the standard leg strap.

Comment: Correct, with a little DIY instructions i guess.

Comment: My LBS charges $1 for a similar strap and it includes reflective material as a bonus.

Comment: Manufactured leg straps may include elastic, but I'm guessing the home-made velcro doesn't stretch. I have velcro leg straps, and the elastic helps it stay secure and comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

This product should work, Leg Shield. Covers your pant leg from your ankle to right below your knee.

http://www.bikelegstrap.com/

Comment: That would be a "gaitor", a well-known variation on the leg strap, though also used by cross-country skiers, et al.  And very much similar to Scrooge McDuck's "spats" (AKA "ankle blankets").

Answer (score 1):

Just the act of rolling up your pant leg one or two times usually covers the problem of it getting caught in the gears.

I've also resorted to tucking it into my socks. It seems silly to buy clamps and devices when these two "free" options are available.

Nice that it's enough of an issue that it's being brought up online. When I started mountain biking, some of the magazines and online sites basically accused a person of being a "dork" if they didn't dress in the appropriate gear.

I don't want to wear tight padded pants just to ride my bike. I've been wearing a t-shirt and jeans for riding for about 4 years now. I wear them in the summer too. I figure my legs will be more protected should I fall, wearing canvas than they'd ever be in a goofy, padded pair of semi-shorts.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the elastic ankle cuffs I've cut off old pants (I use the elastic waist bands cut from old pants to hold plastic bags tight around the outer rims of trash bins) - in a pinch I've tried self-sticking ace bandages to wrap around pant bottoms.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easiest by taking some light weight sheet metal cut it to shape to my gear cover/guard and had a friend wield it over the cover it helps a lot. If u want it to match your bike paint it first. Make sure u use heat resistant paint.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lancasterarchery.com/x-spot-huntsman-camo-armguard.html

I use a arm guard for shooting archery ... they come in several sizes styles and colors ... been using them for my pant leg for years... quick on and off and they work perfect ...

Lot more durable than the neoprene and dosent make my leg sweat. .

http://www.lancasterarchery.com/saunders-diamond-defendertm-armguard-black.html

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.SE] @Rusty. Since you are recommending a product you should make clear any affiliation you have, or say you have none if that is the case.

Answer (score -2):

What I do is just get some electrical or duct tape and wrap it tightly around my ankle.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Why is this solution superior to others mentioned? Are there any drawbacks? Etc. A short, one line answer like this is likely to be downvoted and possibly deleted.

Comment: I'd think this would leave sticky adhesive on your clothes.  So, the trick would be first wrap with the adhesive layer facing out, then reverse direction and a second wrap with the adhesive facing inwards.  So you have a plastic band with no visible sticky bits.
I still go with the cuff into the sock... I'm never without my socks.